# How do you save input data in input html boxes when switching pages?

Tags: javascript, html, search

I have an html input type for a search bar, and currently I'm saving the input to sessionStorage so that I can load it on the next page after the search button is clicked (so that the search box will contain the previous query). The problem is that when you hit the back button in the browser, it isn't loading the previous query--it's loading the most recent one.

I understand why this isn't working, but I don't get how to implement it so the input box displays the appropriate search query. Any ideas?

Example:

From homescreen I search "Query1" and it takes me to the results page. The search bar at the top of the page now displays "Query1" autofilled in it. I go up and search again, this time "Query2". The next results page displays "Query2" filled into the search bar. I hit the backspace in the browser, and here's the problem. It still has "Query2" displayed, when I would want it to be displaying "Query1".

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing the query as a parameter arg to your results page.  Then wire up your input box to check for and consume the param if it exists.

I believe it'd look something like https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-bbz1t4

Some simple HTML

```
<form id="myform" onsubmit="submit()">
  <input id="query" />
  <button type="submit">
  submit
  </button>
</form>
```

And JS to shuffle values in and out of the url params

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

function init() {
  //Set value of input
    document.getElementById('query').value = urlParams.get('q');
}

document.onsubmit = function() {
  //May or maynot be necessary
  event.preventDefault();

  document.getElementById('myform').action += "q=" + document.getElementById('query').value;
  document.location = document.getElementById('myform').action;
}

init();
```

Comment: Specifically, I'm loading the page after each search using a form with action="" -- how do I send in a parameter to this to load and use as a default value to the search bar?